# How can I correct for Aspect Ratio when rotating a Normalised Device Coordinate based view?

Tags: opengl, rotation, coordinates, transformation

I have an OpenGL 2D graphics display. The display uses Normalised Device Coordinates (i.e. -1 to +1 in the horizontal direction, -1 to +1 across the view in the vertical direction and the Origin at the center of the view). I can enable Panning and Zooming In/Out of objects displayed in the view with my mouse.

Almost all computer displays today have non-square aspect ratio (e.g. 16:9 width to height ratio). So the -1 to +1 spacing occupies a smaller physical distance in the vertical direction than in the horizontal direction. For example; a line or a line of equally spaced points will appear physically shorter when rotated from horizontal alignment to pointing in the vertical direction.

How can I rotate the view and dynamically correct for the non-square aspect ratio of the view?  So that a line will maintain the same length in the display when it is rotated from horizontal alignment to vertical alignment - resulting in part of the line appearing to be 'clipped' by the view frame.

Comment: You are probably looking for a projection matrix?

Comment: please show how you draw the line right now. do you have a vertex shader? or are you using legacy opengl?

Comment: It's typical to first apply a matrix that makes the units square. So you make it for example -16 to +16 in the X direction and -9 to +9 in the Y direction - that is, you could make a matrix that shrinks the X direction 16 times and the Y direction 9 times. Now as long as you do everything else based on this first matrix, they are square and they stay square as you rotate.

Comment: Yakov,  Yes, I am using a vertex shader and all my GL code is using modern OpenGL and GLM. The vertex shader simply uses a model matrix to transform each vertex.  It is a 'flat' 2D display. I haven't set up any projection per se, so everything is in NDC (-1 to 1 on either end), so there is no 3D perspective or 2D orthographic projection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your viewport is of size `(w,h)`, you set up a projection matrix that would translate pixel coordinates to NDC:

```
    [ 2/w  0  0 -1 ]
P = [ 0   2/h 0 -1 ]
    [ 0    0  1  0 ]
    [ 0    0  0  1 ]
```

(This one assigns the bottom-left corner as (0,0) and top-right as (w,h). You can use `glm::ortho` instead if you like.)

Pass it to the vertex shader, and apply it after the model-view matrix:

```
in vec4 position;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 MV;
void main() {
    gl_Position = P * MV * position;
}
```

Now you can specify all your positions in pixels. When you apply a rotation in MV, it will rotate the pixel-position before the translation to NDC happens, thus keeping the aspect ratio of your 2D model.